# How to drop a datafile of an already dropped tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

In an 18c Oracle database I have a tablespace that has been dropped. I need to add this tablespace anew, but when I try to do so I get this error:

> ORA-01537: cannot add file 'MYTABLESPACE.DBF' - file already part of database

By the way I create my tablespace like this:

`CREATE TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE DATAFILE 'MYTABLESPACE.DBF' SIZE 1024M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 102400K`

I know that I can use `ALTER` to remove a datafile like this:

`ALTER TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE DROP DATAFILE '{path}\MYTABLESPACE.DBF';`

But this doesn't work, and I get:

> ORA-00959: tablespace does not exist

When I run:

`SELECT* FROM v$datafile`

I can see the datafile with the Id of dropped tablespace listed as online. When I query the `TS$` table:

`SELECT * FROM TS$`

I can see that the tablespace is dropped (`ONLINE$` column has the value of 3).

I know that I can change the name of tablespace and datafile, but for reasons I need them to stay the same. The question is, how do I get rid of this orphaned datafile?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You might want to provide the actual results of the `SELECT * FROM v$datafile` and `SELECT * FROM TS$` statements. There could be a simple error in the `CREATE TABLESPACE...` statement that becomes obvious once the community can see your output. Hit [edit] to add more details. Thanks.

Comment: In order to drop a datafile you will need to drop the whole tablespaces, in oracle at least. Because the controlfile doesn't know that you have deleted the file, there is a workaround which is inofficial, but you could recreate the controlfile without the datafile (needs downtime, wouldn't do it anyways, because the risk is too high).